# The print output to real printer is different than the one with virtual printer in java

Tags: java

In my app the following code prints front and back sides of card. On virtual printers (like Virtual PDF printer, ImagePrinter Pro and Microsoft XPS Document Writer) the output is correct. But when i tested it on real printer, it only printed half of the image in width, moreover the height is correct. I tested with A4 and Letter formates, but all in vane. Dont khow what's the problem.

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

        int w = 360, h = 240;
        int padding = 2;

        BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(w * 2, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D tempG = temp.createGraphics();

        tempG.drawImage(card.getFrontImage(), 0,  0,
                w, h, null);
        tempG.drawImage(card.getBackImage(),  w, 0,
                w, h, null);
        tempG.dispose();

        g2d.drawImage(temp, (int) 0, 0 + padding,
                (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth(), (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight()/5, null);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: How do you establish the PageFormat?

Comment: Didn't even touch it. Can't figure out what to do with PageFormat.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple example...

The `PageFormat` can be established manually (as in the example) or from the printer selection dialog

```
public class TestPrint implements Printable  {

    private BufferedImage background;
    public static final float DPI = 72;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPrint();
    }

    public TestPrint() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                try {
                    background = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/MgkGrl_Yuki_by_fredrin.jpg"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                float width = cmToPixel(21f, DPI);
                float height = cmToPixel(29.7f, DPI);

                Paper paper = new Paper();
                float margin = cmToPixel(1, DPI);
                paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, width - (margin * 2), height - (margin * 2));
                PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
                pf.setPaper(paper);

                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(Math.round(width), Math.round(height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, width, height));
                try {
                    g2d.setClip(new Rectangle2D.Double(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY(), pf.getImageableWidth(), pf.getImageableHeight()));
                    print(g2d, pf, 0);
                } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                g2d.dispose();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

    public float cmToPixel(float cm, float dpi) {

        return (dpi / 2.54f) * cm;

    }

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) throws PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        g.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
        if (background != null) {

            int x = (int)Math.round((pageFormat.getImageableWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2f);
            int y = (int)Math.round((pageFormat.getImageableHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2f);

            g.drawImage(background, x, y, null);

        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, pageFormat.getImageableWidth() - 1, pageFormat.getImageableHeight() - 1));

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really enhanced my knowledge base about this printing stuff. but the problem is still there. My code prints only one card (a stretched one) in width. I have set up a loop to print 5 cards, and thats working but the back side of each card doesn't print.

Comment: So, you're printing both sides on a A4 page? What size are the cards and what size is the image?